# select the highest value in a set of 3 numbers using flash as3

Tags: javascript, flash, actionscript-3, math

I have a set of variables of type "integer" and I just want to take the greatest of these values, and set as the value for some new variable. How would I do this in as3? (or any language, I suppose)

Answer (score 10, accepted):

ActionScript 3:

```
var highest:Number = Math.max(first, second, third);
```

where first, second and third are Numbers or ints.

Comment: Cool, I'm not an actionscript developer but it's nice to see Math.max take more than two arguments.

Comment: Awesome - I live off AS3 and I didn't even know that one.

Answer (score 1):

```
Math.max(var1, Math.max(var2, var3))
```